# discord.py hybrid commands not working on vps

Tags: python, websocket, discord.py, vps

I have a discord bot(discord.py 2.3.2).
Problem with hybrid commands when I try to use the slash command (problem in the screenshot).
[discord message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEqNf.png)

A normal message is sent instantly, but ephemeral does not work in this case and the error “The application did not respond” is displayed. There are no exceptions in the application.
The most interesting thing is that this problem only occurs on vps. Locally there are no problems.
Code snippet:

```
class Info(cogs.base.Base):
     @commands.hybrid_command()     
     async def test(self, context: Context):
         await context.send("Hello")
```

What I tried:

- The setup is absolutely the same (locally and VPS). I tried running everything in a docker container - the behavior is the same, everything works locally, but not on the VPS. All library versions and Python version are fixed.
- I changed the firewall settings and disabled it completely, and also opened all ports through the VPS control panel. There were no changes.
- I also tried changing the code using context.channel.send(), context.reply(), adding context.defer() (context.defer() results in the screenshot).
  [result with defer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uknL2.png)

Comment: Do you have more code snippets or example to show? Also, if it does not respond, this is  usually caused by an error. Check terminal and logging to see if any error is shown.